# TypeORM changes my submission object data when trying to save to database

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I have some problem to insert my data in database using TypeORM

My problem:
What I need send to the database is the following data:
Title, Description, Userid,idCategoryService and createdBy. Where id's and title are not null

My route:

```
public async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<Response> {
    try {
        const idUser = req.context?.userId;
        const service = req.body;
        await serviceSchema.validateAsync(service, opts);

    const serviceRepository = getRepository(Service);
    const existsService = await serviceRepository.findOne({
        where: {
            title: service.title, serviceCategory: service.idServiceCategory, user: idUser
        }
    });

    if (existsService) return this.sendErrorResponse(res, { code: 409, message: ['Service already created'] });
    const newService: Service = Object.assign(new Service(), { ...service, idUser: idUser, createdBy: idUser });
    console.log(newService)
    await serviceRepository.save(newService);
    return res.status(201).send({
        code: 201,
        message: 'Success',
        data: [newService]
    })
} catch (error) {
    return this.sendCreateUpdateErrorResponse(res, error);
}
```

}

When object is created with the Object assign:
Showing in `console.log()`

```
Service {
  title: 'Test1',
  description: 'Test2',
  idServiceCategory: 'e704a4c4-b984-493f-877c-d5b6f4fdeb5b',
  idUser: '32ce26fa-bebe-4cdd-af40-f3e338ba2b5c',
  createdBy: '32ce26fa-bebe-4cdd-af40-f3e338ba2b5c'
}
```

But look what was passed in the typeorm log:

```
query: INSERT INTO "ijob_api"."Service"("id", "createdAt", "updatedAt", "title", "description", "createdBy", "closed", "idUser", "idServiceCategory") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) RETURNING "createdAt", "updatedAt" -- PARAMETERS: ["d458357e-7120-4d78-b66b-5b2a410efe79","2021-08-30T14:43:25.944Z","2021-08-30T14:43:25.944Z","Test1","Test2","32ce26fa-bebe-4cdd-af40-f3e338ba2b5c",0]
```

My idUser stay 0

like this my driver error in postgresql

```
 driverError: error: null value in column "idUser" of relation "Service" violates not-null constraint
//code: 23502 -- postgres
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm find an solution, my problem was in this method:

```
const newService: Service = Object.assign(new Service(), { ...service, idUser: idUser, createdBy: idUser });
```

instead of passing the userid, I passed the user and finally the userid

Example:

```
const newService: Service = Object.assign(new Service(), { user: idUser, ...service, createdBy: idUser });
```